# Encoding characters in C, high nibble calulcation error

Tags: c, binary, encode

I am trying to encode the char "A" which in Binary is: 0100 0001.

When encoding this I expect the output in my output file to be dq (d = the high nibble, q = the low nibble).

As for now I got the q right, so the low nibble keeps being correct. However, I never get the d. With the following code the binary should be expected like this:

```
Input byte: 0100 0001 (A)
Encoded byte high: 0110 0100 (d)
Encoded byte low: 0111 0001 (q)
```

But I get:

```
Input byte: 0100 0001 (A)
Encoded byte high: 1100 0100 (�)
Encoded byte low: 0111 0001 (q)
```

This is my whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

bool encodeByte(uint8_t inputByte, uint8_t* encodedByteHigh, uint8_t* encodedByteLow) {
uint8_t p0, p1, p2;
uint8_t d0, d1, d2, d3;

d0 = (inputByte >> 0) & 0x01;
d1 = (inputByte >> 1) & 0x01;
d2 = (inputByte >> 2) & 0x01;
d3 = (inputByte >> 3) & 0x01;

p0 = d0 ^ d1 ^ d2;
p1 = d0 ^ d1 ^ d3;
p2 = d0 ^ d2 ^ d3;

if (p0 == 0) {
    *encodedByteLow = inputByte & 0x0F;
} else {
    *encodedByteLow = inputByte | 0x10;
}

if (p1 == 0) {
    *encodedByteLow = *encodedByteLow & 0x1F;
} else {
    *encodedByteLow = *encodedByteLow | 0x20;
}

if (p2 == 0) {
    *encodedByteLow = *encodedByteLow & 0x3F;
} else {
    *encodedByteLow = *encodedByteLow | 0x40;
}

*encodedByteHigh = inputByte >> 4;

p0 = p0 ^ ((inputByte >> 4) & 0x01);
p1 = p1 ^ ((inputByte >> 5) & 0x01);
p2 = p2 ^ ((inputByte >> 6) & 0x01);

if (p0 == 0) {
    *encodedByteHigh = *encodedByteHigh & 0x7F;
} else {
    *encodedByteHigh = *encodedByteHigh | 0x80;
}

if (p1 == 0) {
    *encodedByteHigh = *encodedByteHigh & 0xBF;
} else {
    *encodedByteHigh = *encodedByteHigh | 0x40;
}

if (p2 == 0) {
    *encodedByteHigh = *encodedByteHigh & 0xDF;
} else {
    *encodedByteHigh = *encodedByteHigh | 0x20;
}

return true;
}

void printBinary(uint8_t byte) {
for (int8_t i = 7; i >= 4; --i) {
    printf("%d", (byte >> i) & 0x01);
}
printf(" ");
for (int8_t i = 3; i >= 0; --i) {
    printf("%d", (byte >> i) & 0x01);
}
}

int main() {
FILE* inputFile = fopen("inputData.txt", "r");
FILE* outputFile = fopen("encodedData.txt", "w");

if (inputFile == NULL || outputFile == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open files.\n");
    return 1;
}

uint8_t inputByte;
uint8_t encodedByteHigh;
uint8_t encodedByteLow;

while (fscanf(inputFile, "%c", &inputByte) != EOF) {
    encodeByte(inputByte, &encodedByteHigh, &encodedByteLow);
    fprintf(outputFile, "%c%c", encodedByteHigh, encodedByteLow);
    //print inputbyte, encodedbytehigh, encodedbytelow
    printf("Input byte: ");
    printBinary(inputByte);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Encoded byte high: ");
    printBinary(encodedByteHigh);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Encoded byte low: ");
    printBinary(encodedByteLow);
    printf("\n");
}

fclose(inputFile);
fclose(outputFile);

printf("Encoding complete.\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect that `0100` is encoded as `0110 0100`?

Comment: I am still learning c and what I am doing right now so excuse me if I say something incorrect.

The idea is that the high and low nibble will be seperated and that both of them will get parity bits just like it went with succes when looking at the low. the idea is that later I will make a program that will represent "noise" to flip some bits and then fix+decode it later usng the parity bits. My calculations using the bitwise operators made me think that 0100 will first be shifted 4 spots to the right (which it did) and then calculate and then add the parity bits to the 4 bits on the left.

Comment: And why do you expect that the parity bits for `0100` are `0110` and not `1100`?

Comment: This is some kind of error-correcting code? You should explain the algorithm so we can see where you're implementing it wrongly.

Comment: It'd help if you described how the encoding is supposed to work.

Comment: to mkrieger1: I don't know to be honest. I am still learning this concept while reaching a deadline. what I do know is that the parity bits should be 0110 since that got shown to us in a example demo.

to Barmar: This program shown in my question is not a error correcting code, but I am busy no that as well. This code is purely for encoding whatever the data is in the input file

Comment: But, by what rules are you encoding? Do you have a description of how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Ted Lyngmo, I am still trying to understand that as well, which is a weak answer I know. but as far I understand the idea is that the data (d0, d1,d2, d3) is checken and then compared what the parity (p0, p1, p3) is.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand it. Without a description of the algorithm, you'll have to reverse engineer it. If all else fails, just make a mapping between the 16 possible inputs in a nibble and map them to the expected output. `uint8_t map[16] = { values.... };`

Comment: I did what you told me and I found the result that I needed, Thank you for your answer and effort Ted. Like mentioned earlier I am still trying to understand it and trying to go through each step to the point that I can explain it to myself is a goal, would you like me to get back to you and give the description?

Comment: @skullyurd Great, you're welcome! Sure, update the question if you happen to get hold of the algorithm and I may catch it. If you also put your nibble->encoding map in the question, there's a pretty good chance that one of the bit twiddlers here sees the pattern and can help formulate the algorithm from that.

Comment: Hi, excuse me for my late update. My whole approach was wrong from the beginning but somehow roughly 80% of my tests was correct which made it look correct with some small errors here and there. it should work as follow: You fill in any character. The calculation will separate the high and low nibble and will calculate the parity bits for each nibble. The reason why is that when in the end a bit gets flipped, the parity bits can be used to calculate what the original nibbles were.